# How to change the state of the checkbox?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am designing an UI for mobile application.
how can i implement a check box which changes its state from false to true or vise-versa?

```
bool _value1 = false;
new CheckboxListTile(
        value: _value1,
        onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() => _value1 = val),
        title: new Text('Remember me'),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
      ),
```

i am not getting any error but when i click the checkbox its not changing its state.

edit: The full code goes like this -

```
bool _value1 = false;
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/background.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 258.0),
        username,
        SizedBox(height: 22.0),
        password,
        SizedBox(height: 4.0),
          new CheckboxListTile(
            value: _value1,
            onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() => _value1 = val),
            title: new Text('Remember me'),
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            activeColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
        loginButton,
          SizedBox(height: 58.0),
          new Text(' Version 1.1'),
        ],
    ) ,
  ),
);
```

where return scaffold is inside

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
 static String tag = 'login-page';
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {.....}
```

username and password and loginbutton are the other widgets.

Comment: Please share the full code where you're using the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem, you have to put outside this: `bool _value1 = false;` Every time you call `setState`, your are telling the framework to rebuild, so the build method its called again, thats what setState do, its like your calling build method again. 
So the solution its put `bool _value1 = false;` outside the build method, so the var can change, right now it's always false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you used it in the wrong way. 
Try the code below:

```dart
bool _value1 = false;
new CheckboxListTile(
        value: _value1,
        onChanged: () {
          if (_value1 == false) {
            setState(() => _value1 = true)
          } else {
            setState(() => _value1 = false)
          }
        },
        title: new Text('Remember me'),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
      ),
```

Comment: i am unable to use it like this. it results in an error - the argument type Null Function() cant be assigned to parameter type void Function(bool)